# What should be the correct MySql collation store in this case?

Tags: mysql, unicode, collation

I'm storing strings on a Mysql database.

Some of the strings have single quotes which then get stored like this:

Peopleâ€™s

Is this the proper way to store these strings or should I set a different mysql collation?

I have tried the following without luck....

utf8_general_ci

latin1_swedish_ci

Comment: Related reading: [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where are you setting the collation? You should be using UTF-8 in three places:

1. as the collation of each row that contains character data. You can set the default collation for the table or database so that new columns pick it up, but if you already have a table, ALTERing its default collation doesn't change the collation of the existing rows.
2. as the encoding of the connection between your application and MySQL. This can be set manually using the `SET NAMES` statement, or, better, with the suitable API call for your environment (for example `mysql_set_charset()` in PHP, or the `charset` argument to `connect()` in Python MySQLdb).
3. in your output. For example if producing a web page, by using the `Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8` header/meta.

You *can* store the string "People’s" as UTF-8-hidden-in-Latin-1 "Peopleâ€™s" by using Latin-1 throughout, since you'll still get the same bytes out as you put in. But that way you won't get sensible results from ordering or case-insenstive-comparisons of non-ASCII characters.